# Tic-Tac-Toe programming

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a program for homework that displays a Tic-Tac-Toe board, and when the user clicks the button it displays a random number in all of the boxes. The number 1 = "X" and 0 = "O". I created 9 labels labeled "label1, label2...etc". Once the labels are full, I need to display who won, the letter X or O. I'm using arrays for this but am kinda of lost at this point. what do I need to do to display the random numbers into the labels. Here is the code I've written for the click event handler so far.

```
Random rand = new Random(2);
int click;

click = rand.Next(2);
const int ROWS = 3;
const int COLS = 3;

int[,] letters = new int[ROWS,COLS];

int ROW = ROWS;
int COL = COLS;
for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; ROW ++) {
  for (int col = 0; col < COLS; COL ++) {
    letters[row, col] = rand.Next(2);
    int X = 1;//???
    int O = 0;//???
    label1.Text = [ROW,COL].ToString();//???
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the requirements. There is nothing about the game of Tic-Tac-Toe that involves random numbers.

Comment: You need to have a flag set for which players turn it is, then you can set the value of the button to X or O depending on whose turn it currently is.  You should then check if any player has 3 in a row and wins after that move is made.

Comment: @Jonathan Wood: It's tic-tac-toe but with 1 for X and 0 for O.

Comment: @ Jonathan Wood, @jzworkman No one is actually playing, When the "Start Game" button is clicked, it automatically plays a game, and displays who won.

Comment: You need to post more of your code.  You need to also think about trying to clarify your question.

Comment: @EASTON should this have AI involved then to make correct moves(random moves seems like it would not have any real benefit) if so this is a much more complex problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here an attempt at an explanation:

first, you have the data to represent your problem:

```
const int ROWCOUNT = 3;
const int COLCOUNT = 3;
private int[,] letters = new int[ROWCOUNT,COLCOUNT];
Random rand = new Random(DateTime.Now.Ticks);
```

then you want to randomly fill that data:

```
private void randomize()
{
    for( int row = 0; row < ROWCOUNT; row++ ){ //start with row=0, do row=row+1 until row no longer < ROWCOUNT
      for( int col = 0; col < COLCOUNT; col++ ){
         letters[row,col] = rand.nextInt(2);
      }
    }
}
```

finally, you want to display the array somewhere (in your case labels):

```
//These need to be added to a GridLayoutManager
private JLabel[,] labels = new JLabel[ROWCOUNT,COLCOUNT];

private void updateView(){
    for( int row = 0; row < ROWCOUNT; row++ ){ //start with row=0, do row=row+1 until row no longer < ROWCOUNT
      for( int col = 0; col < COLCOUNT; col++ ){
         var current = letters[row,col];
         var labelText = "O";
         if( current > 0 ) 
            labelText = "X";
         labels[row,col].Text = labelText;
      }
    }
}
```

so, when the user clicks the button, you call:

```
randomize();
updateView();
```

hope it helps

from your comments, it seems setting the Label Text needs more explanation:

```
     var labelText = "O";
     if( current > 0 ) 
        labelText = "X";
     labels[row,col].Text = labelText;
```

maybe, i should have written it more like this:

```
     String textForLabel = "O"; //0 represents O, 1 represents X
     //test to see, if it really is a 0, not a 1
     if( current != 0 ){
        //oh, it is not a zero, therefore, set 
        textForLabel = "X";
     }
     JLabel labelAtRowAndCol = labels[row,col];
     labelAtRowAndCol.Text = textForLabel;
```

Comment: to figure out who won, create another method and use the same loop, counting the 0 and 1 by row or column

Comment: Thank you for your help, but to be honest I'm new at this, what would I just need to do from using my code to display the different x or o's in the labels I created. That part has me stuck. Also what can I do since I can't explicitly set "string X = 1"??? I've never heard or used a Jlabel before. Ill be able to figure out to display who won after I can figure this part out. Thank you for your help

Comment: I made a few adjustments. I'm thinking about using a cast for the letter x and o. As for, how to display the different letters in the label, I'm still lost.

Comment: for(int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < COLS; col++)
            {

                letters[ROWS, COLS] = rand.Next(2);
                 
   int anX = 1
   int anO = 0
   float O = an0
   float X = anX

Answer (score 0):

I refuse to provide you the exact answer since you learning how to dot his is the entire point of this excerise.

Before I started the game I would randomly choose the first move: X or O.

I would then do the following:

1) I would place all the Labels into a collection.
2) I would randomly choose one of the Labels within the collection and change the Text property.
3) I would then remove the same Label from the collection
4) Rinse and Repeat.

You DO NOT need a two diminsional array for this.

In order to figure out the winner...I would keep track of the moves of each player.  There is only a static number of winning moves in this game.  Would be a simple task to determine if there were three X's in the top row or not.

Comment: It states in the instructions to use a 2d array. Also no one is playing the game its a simulator.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<set>
using namespace std;

    char s[3][3] = {{'*','*','*'},{'*','*','*'},{'*','*','*'}};
    void show(char os[3][3]);
    int def[9];
    void changeo(int n);
    void changex(int n);
    int stop();
    set<int> cset;
    int search (int n){

    }

int main(){
    int n;  show(s);
    int ss = 2;
    cout<<endl;
    while (stop()){

        if (ss%2==0){
            cout<<"player One(O) : enter n "; cin>>n;

            if (!cset.count(n) && n<10){
            cset.insert(n);
            changeo(n);
            show(s);
            ss++;
            }
            else{
                cout<<"invalid move"<<endl;
            }

        }
        else{

            cout<<"player Two(X) : enter n "; cin>>n;
            if (!cset.count(n)&& n<10){
            cset.insert(n);
            changex(n);
            show(s);
            ss++;   
            }

        }


    }
    cout<<"\nyou can see the winner"<<endl;
    cout<<"your moves are "<<ss;
    return 0;
}

void show(char s[3][3]){
    cout<< setw(7)<< "1: " <<s[0][0]<<setw(5)<<"2: " <<s[0][1]<<setw(5)<<"3: " <<s[0][2]<<endl;
    cout<< setw(7)<< "4: " <<s[1][0]<<setw(5)<<"5: " <<s[1][1]<<setw(5)<<"6: " <<s[1][2]<<endl;
    cout<< setw(7)<< "7: " <<s[2][0]<<setw(5)<<"8: " <<s[2][1]<<setw(5)<<"9: " <<s[2][2]<<endl;
    cout<<endl;
}
void changeo(int n){
    switch(n){
        case 1:
            s[0][0] = 'O';
            break;
        case 2:
            s[0][1] = 'O';
            break;
        case 3:
            s[0][2] = 'O';
            break;
        case 4:
            s[1][0] = 'O';
            break;
        case 5:
            s[1][1] = 'O';
            break;
        case 6:
            s[1][2] = 'O';
            break;
        case 7:
            s[2][0] = 'O';
            break;
        case 8:
            s[2][1] = 'O';
            break;
        case 9:
            s[2][2] = 'O';
            break;
    }
}

void changex(int n){
    switch(n){
        case 1:
            s[0][0] = 'X';
            break;
        case 2:
            s[0][1] = 'X';
            break;
        case 3:
            s[0][2] = 'X';
            break;
        case 4:
            s[1][0] = 'X';
            break;
        case 5:
            s[1][1] = 'X';
            break;
        case 6:
            s[1][2] = 'X';
            break;
        case 7:
            s[2][0] = 'X';
            break;
        case 8:
            s[2][1] = 'X';
            break;
        case 9:
            s[2][2] = 'X';
            break;
    }
}
int stop(){
    int m=0;
        for (int i=0; i<3; i++){
            for (int j=0; j<3; j++){
                if(s[i][j]=='*'){
                    m=1;
                    break;
                }

            }
        }
        return m;
    }
```